# How to install numpy and scipy on OSX?

Tags: python, macos, numpy, scipy

I'm new to Mac so please bear with me.

I'm using snow leopard 10.6.4 at the moment.

I want to install numpy and scipy, so I downloaded the python2.6,numpy and scipy dmg files from their official site. However, I'm having problem import numpy:

```
Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

Can anyone shed some light to this problem?

Comment: Use the [SciPy Superpack](https://public.me.com/ix/fonnesbeck/superpack_10.6_2010.12.15.sh) installer script by Chris Fonnesbeck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds as though you might be trying to use a 32-bit library from a 64-bit Python. Looks like there's an unofficial [64-bit Numpy available for Snow Leopard](http://www.scipy.org/Download#head-eb99a6ef6be4f9225176b355d92f2afb59a90602).

---

EDIT: The Python 2.6 .dmg available [here](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6/) is indeed 32-bit. (Specifically, it's a universal binary containing both i386 and ppc versions). The same is true of the regular numpy and scipy .dmg releases available [here](http://www.scipy.org/Download). (How do I know? See below!) So if you use those releases together you should be fine.

But you're not fine - so my guess is you're not using the version of Python from the 2.6 .dmg you downloaded. If you're running an executable python script, e.g.:

```
$ ./my-script.py
```

then you could try specifying the Python you're using explicitly on the command line. Looks like the MacPython .dmg installs to /usr/local/bin/python, so try:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/python2.6 myscript.py
```

Any joy?

---

How I determined the architecture the contents of those .dmg files are built for...

1. Mount the .dmg (i.e. double-click it to open a volume)
2. Use gunzip and pax to unpack the package contents to a local directory, e.g.:

   ```
   $ mkdir tmp
   $ cd tmp
   $ gunzip -c /Volumes/Universal\ MacPython\ 2.6/MacPython.mpkg/Contents/Packages/PythonUnixTools-2.6.pkg/Contents/Archive.pax.gz | pax
   ```
3. Use `file` to examine binary files in the package contents

   ```
   $ file Versions/2.6/bin/python
   Versions/2.6/bin/python: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
   Versions/2.6/bin/python (for architecture ppc): Mach-O executable ppc
   Versions/2.6/bin/python (for architecture i386):    Mach-O executable i386
   ```

Comment: isn't the python installer from python.org built as 32-bit?

Comment: Even if the python.org installer is 32-bit, the OS X python (installed by default) is probably 64-bit.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error message when I was trying my freshly-installed numpy and scipy in python2.7 on Mac OSX 10.6.8 . Later I found out that there were two .dmg for python2.7:

- numpy-1.6.2-py2.7-python.org-macosx10.3.dmg
- numpy-1.6.2-py2.7-python.org-macosx10.6.dmg

It was the package in 10.3.dmg giving me the error message about multiarray.so.
After installing the one in 10.6.dmg, I got rid of this error message.

Answer (score 3):

I had problems with numpy until I installed in a virtualenv, now I don't have any issues.  I would definitely suggest trying that.

Answer (score 1):

for snow leopard 64 bit i used the following man 
http://blog.hyperjeff.net/?p=160
just execute and you are good to go.
Also look at the comments ( new AMD ...)

building numpy works all the time. but for scipy you need to provide the numpy config files.
install gfortran .....

Answer (score 0):

The best way to manage packages on OS X is [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) (not MacPorts :) ). They have good Python, NumPy, and SciPy support.

Why use a package manager?  because you will not only get NumPy and SciPy, but also many other programs that you will inevitably need, all with a single point of entry (basically the install command of the manager).  This is much more convenient than having to hunt for specific compiled versions of the programs that you want to install.

Why Fink?  because Fink is reputedly more stable than MacPorts, and has many more packages.

Comment: Actually, the best way to manage packages on OS X is [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) (not Fink or MacPorts :)) - which unfortunately lists neither NumPy now SciPy at the current time. :)

Comment: Wow. I had no idea there was such competition over OS X package managers. (Just got my first ever down vote!) Do you know if Fink and MacPorts can cohabit without fighting, so that I can play with it a little?

Comment: @Josh: I guess that you can have both MacPorts and Darwin packages installed at the same time: Fink installs everything in a dedicated /sw directory, as far as I know.

Comment: There is no direct conflict between MacPorts and Fink packages as they are installed to different roots by default, `/opt/local/` and `/sw` respectively.  However there are some packages available in either or both whose vanilla installation process try to be clever by looking for 3rd-party libraries in both MacPorts and Fink default locations and which may not have been customized by MacPorts or Fink to prevent that, which can result in a package using a mismatch of libraries from the wrong package manager and failing in execution because of incompatible build options (archs, etc).

Comment: ... For that reason, it is generally not a good idea to have the same packages or packages dependencies installed from more than one package manager (or from source yourself, say, to /usr/local) at the same time.  Stick to one at a time unless you are really sure of what you are doing.

Comment: @EOL: not sure what you mean by *Darwin* packages.  If you are referring to *DarwinPorts*, be aware that the information on the DarwinPorts website is basically an incorrect and unofficial ripoff of MacPorts and should be avoided.  See here for more info: http://trac.macports.org/wiki/DarwinPortsFraud

Comment: @Ned: Oops!  I meant "Fink".  I have no idea why I wrote "Darwin" instead, besides the fact that it was about 2 AM. :)

Answer (score 0):

No need to use MacPorts or Fink.

Use the [Python 2.6 installer](http://python.org/ftp/python/2.6.6/python-2.6.6-macosx10.3.dmg) and [this Numpy installer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.5.1/numpy-1.5.1-py2.6-python.org-macosx10.3.dmg/download). I think you need to have Numpy installed first, then install [Scipy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/0.8.0/scipy-0.8.0-py2.6-python.org.dmg/download), and everything will work auto-magically. I remember that for a while, I needed to explicitly [append the path](http://www.johnny-lin.com/cdat_tips/tips_pylang/path.html) to the site-packages directory at the top of my scripts for Python to know where to look.

Comment: What code gave you the error you listed above? Had you previously tried to build any of those packages yourself? You might want to delete the numpy and scipy folders from site-packages completely and try again.

Answer (score 0):

In case this is useful to someone, I also had problems installing numpy's binaries on OSX. The installer complained telling me that:

> You cannot install numpy 1.5.1 on this volume. numpy requires System Python 2.6 to install.

**Long story short:** “System Python” means “python from [python.org](http://www.python.org/download/releases/)” and “2.6” means *really* 2.6, not 2.5 and not 2.7. So, go and find the installer for the version of python that numpy wants and then all is great.

On my first attempt I understood numpy's error as telling me that I had an outdated python, so I got the latest version (2.7 at the time), but numpy kept complaining all the same. Only after a careful reading of the message I understood that it *really* wanted 2.6 and not any other version. I trashed the first installation (found in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`) and installed 2.6 after that. Finally numpy was happy to install and everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent countless hours browsing the web, trying to get various python packages working in OS X.  In the end, I found the easiest solution was to either switch entirely to Ubuntu or run Ubuntu in Virtualbox from within OS X (all free of cost).

Using Ubuntu's package manager, apt-get, virtually any package you want will work out of the box after one simple install command.  It was a huge rush the first time I got numpy, scipy, and matplotlib up and running in less than a minute.

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib
```

I still get a mini-rush every time I do that.  Not sure if there is a debian package for the module you want?  Typically there is, and you can search for, say, python's lxml module with:

```
$ apt-cache search lxml | grep python
```