# Python Pandas: can't find numpy.core.multiarray when importing pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm trying to get my code (running in eclipse) to import pandas.

I get the following error: `"ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import"`when I try to import pandas. I'm using `python2.7`, `pandas 0.7.1`, and `numpy 1.5.1`

Comment: sorry looks like the 1.6.1numpy fixed this issue..thanks anyway

Comment: Issue not fixed for me even with 1.6.1 numpy -- how can this be fixed? This happens to me on ubuntu, so it's not mac os x specific

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure:

- Did you install pandas from the sources ? Make sure it's using the version of NumPy you want.
- Did you upgrade NumPy after installing pandas?  Make sure to recompile pandas, as there can be some changes in the ABI (but w/ that version of NumPy, I doubt it's the case)
- Are you calling pandas and/or Numpy from their source directory ? Bad idea, NumPy tends to choke on that.

Answer (score 1):

Try to update to numpy version 1.6.1. Helped for me!

Answer (score 0):

Might be a 32-bit vs 64-bit compatibility issue.  See:
[how to install numpy and scipy on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527338/how-to-install-numpy-and-scipy-on-os-x)

Despite the title, similar problems can occur with other operating systems if you mix 32-bit and 64-fit versions.

Answer (score 0):

@user248237:

I second Keith's suggestion that its probably a 32/64 bit compatibility issue. I ran into the same problem just this week while trying to install a different module.  Check the versions of each of your modules and make everything matches.  In general, I would stick to the 32 bit versions -- not all modules have official 64 bit support.  I uninstalled my 64 bit version of python and replaced it with a 32 bit one, reinstalled the modules, and haven't had any problems since.